# Evaluation of integrals

Tags: integration

I wast to evaluate the following integrals:

\begin{multline} \label{eqlens12}
\int_0^{\infty}\frac{(1+4\lambda^2)}{(1+\lambda^2)\left[\lambda\sin(2\eta_2)+\sinh(2\lambda\eta_2)\right]} \\
\left\{\lambda\sin(2\eta_2)+\sinh(2\lambda\eta_2)+\left[1+2\lambda^2\sin^2\eta_2-\cosh(2\lambda\eta_2)\right]\tanh(\lambda\pi)\right\}\,d\lambda.
\end{multline}
\begin{equation} \label{eqlens11}
\int_0^{\infty}\frac{(1+4\lambda^2)\left\{1+(1+2\lambda^2)\left[3\cosh(\lambda\pi)-\cosh(3\lambda\pi)\right]
-3\cosh(2\lambda\pi)\right\}\,d\lambda}{2(1+\lambda^2)\cosh(\lambda\pi)\left[1+2\lambda^2-\cosh(3\lambda\pi)\right]}.
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\int_0^{\infty}(4\lambda^2+1)\left[1-\tanh(\lambda\eta_2)\tanh(\lambda\pi)\right]\,d\lambda.
\end{equation}
In the first and last integrals $\pi>\eta_2>0$. Would be grateful if anybody can help.

Comment: Have you tried with WolframAlpha?

Comment: Yes, of course. It is able to evaluate the integrals for special values of $\eta_2$ (especially in the last integral, it is able to evaluate for $\eta_2=\pi/4,\pi/2,\pi$ etc. (the upper limit for $\eta_2$ should $\le \pi$ and not $<pi$), but I am not able to find the general expression from these particular cases.